# How to get smooth scrolling with images from url?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make an infinite scroll post view. I am using ScrollView + LazyVStack (if i use a List then the behavior is the same). The Row in this example is similar to the Row in my real project - text, then picture, then more text in vertical stack. The problem is that when I scroll, when the picture appears, twitching starts. I noticed that if you leave only the picture and remove the VStack, then the twitching becomes less, but they are still there. In this example, I am using AsyncImage from ios 15, but the same behavior with pictures from Nuke, SDWebImage and others. How can i get smooth scrolling without twitching?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let urls: [URL] = [
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-05/1556945414_2.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426537_1.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426563_6.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426524_3.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426502_5.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426571_23.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426508_4.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426506_2.jpg")!,
        URL(string: "https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-12/1544426569_9.jpg")!
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
                    Row(url: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    let url: URL
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(url.absoluteString)
                .font(.body)
            
            // Here can be Nuke, SDWebImage or something else
            AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
            .frame(width: width, height: width * 1.666666666666667) // <- 800/480 image size
            
            Text(url.absoluteString)
                .font(.callout)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a placeholder image and then substituting the actual image when downloaded? Your issue is that it obviously takes time to download the images. Also, you should use a separate class to download the images

Answer (score 0):

As the user scrolls, every time a row is visible the app requests the same image repeatedly. Therefore, I believe you need to cache downloaded images.

- Nuke async image component: https://github.com/kean/NukeUI
- Nuke documentation: https://kean.blog/nuke/guides/caching
- Nuke ScrollViewPrefetching: https://kean.blog/nuke/guides/prefetching (Custom component that offers prefetching capability)